# Converting json to class object

Tags: c#, json, .net, json-deserialization

And I have my object definition as:

```
public class sendSmsResult
{
    public sendSmsResult()
    {
        MessageIdList=new List<MessageId>();
    }
    
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string PacketId { get; set; }
    public List<MessageId> MessageIdList { get; set; }

}

public class MessageId
{
    public MessageId()
    {
        messageid=new List<string>();
    }
    public List<string> messageid { get; set; }
}
```

After executing this:

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I am getting the jsonresult from "response.Content"  as

```
 "{\"sendSmsResult\":{\"ErrorCode\":\"0\",\"PacketId\":\"261633886\",\"MessageIdList\":{\"MessageId\":[\"7096779206\",\"-19\"]}}}"
```

after getting json string I am running this:

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sendSmsResult>(response.Content);
```

gives an error says:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Error
> converting value
> "{"sendSmsResult":{"ErrorCode":"0","PacketId":"261638899","MessageIdList":{"MessageId":["7097068828","-19"]}}}"
> to type 'UME.WebApi.Models.sendSmsResult'. Path '', line 1, position

Comment: In the JSON content, MessageIdList isn't array, it's object. In the class `sendSmsResult`, try `public MessageId MessageIdList { get; set; }`

Comment: What you posted isn't an exception, it's a JSON string containing a serialized exception which makes it *very* hard to read

Comment: In any case, that JSON string doesn't contain a `sendSmsResult` object, it contains another object whose `sendSmsResult` property seems to match your `sendSmsResult` class

Comment: @Vernou that was one thing I was doing wrong, thank you so much. But still does not work.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated my model as below what 500InternalServerError suggested but still gives an error.

Comment: That's still not an exception. Add proper exception handling and logging to your application instead of returning the exception as JSON. What exception do you get this time? What did you actually try?  If the exception complains about something at a specific position, what's there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need wrapper for sendSmsResult, like bellow:

```
class sendSmsResultWrapper {
public sendSmsResult sendSmsResult {get;set;}
}
```

And, typeof `sendSmsResult.MessageIdList` is `MessageId`, not `List<MessageId>`!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, what you suggested is the same as the below suggestion. I tried it but get Could not cast or convert from System.String to UME.WebApi.Models.Root. Which will be "Could not cast or convert from System.String to UME.WebApi.Models.sendSmsResultWrapper"  in your case.

Comment: i tried it in [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5NqKMa). not exception was throw, can you error reproduction?

Comment: This is so strange. I am doing the exact thing that you are doing but I get "Could not cast or convert from System.String to UME.WebApi.Models.sendSmsResultWrapper." error.

Comment: bạn đang sử dụng phiên bản nào của Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: are you sure exception was throw by JsonConvert.DeserializeObject??

Comment: i think you need re-check response.Content, are you sure that like json text you was post? Your exception message will throw if response.Content is "\"some string\""....

Comment: read your comment bellow, i'm pretty sure it's a kind of json in json. Check this [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QVaj66)!!

Comment: That's what the reason is. Thank you so much, initially, it was having leading and trailing back slashes. Converting it to string worked.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth [json2csharp.com](https://json2csharp.com/) (no affiliation) suggests the following class structure for your sample data:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class MessageIdList    {
        public List<string> MessageId { get; set; } 
    }

    public class SendSmsResult    {
        public string ErrorCode { get; set; } 
        public string PacketId { get; set; } 
        public MessageIdList MessageIdList { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public SendSmsResult sendSmsResult { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: I am getting an error says:

       Could not cast or convert from System.String to UME.WebApi.Models.Root.

Inner exception says:
            Error converting value "{"sendSmsResult":{"ErrorCode":"0","PacketId":"261661100","MessageIdList":{"MessageId":["7097954236","-19"]}}}" to type 'UME.WebApi.Models.Root'. Path '', line 1, position 129.

Comment: What's at position 129?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you so much for your time and help. What Hanry suggested work. Initially, the text returning from the rest call had leading and trailing backslashes. Converting it to string and deserialize it to the object I created worked perfectly.